# Android multiple spinners

Tags: android

I have 3 spinners (dropdown menus). I would like the user to select item from the first one and that would determine the options(different string array) on the second and on the third spinner.
E.g. user selects the country in the first spinner and then gets popular music groups in that country on the second spinner and popular dishes on the third.
 What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for selections from the first one, and then set the adapter on the second and third ones.

Comment: Tnx for simple solution, i started complicating.